# Can GPLv3+ library be used as a component of a larger, LPGLv3+ library

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl

The question is in the title. My guess is that the answer is "No", but I would appreciate confirmation.

This [page](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-not-lgpl.en.html) mentions as a downside of the Lesser GPL that using it permits use of the library in proprietary programs, but doesn't seem to touch the subject of use by a Lesser GPL library.